# How to sort all the keys, sub-keys, sub-sub-keys, etc of a dictionary at once?

Tags: python, python-2.7, sorting, dictionary, ordereddict

Is there a way to sort all the keys, sub-keys, sub-sub-keys, etc. of a python dictionary at once?

Let's suppose I have the dictionary

```
dict_1 = { 
            "key9":"value9",
            "key5":"value5",
            "key3":{
                    "key3_1":"value3_1",
                    "key3_3":"value3_3",
                    }
            "key4":"value4",
            "key2":"value2",
            "key8":{
                    "key8_1":"value8_1",
                    "key8_5":[                              
                              "value8_5_3",
                              "value8_5_1",
                              ]
                    "key8_2":"value8_2",
                    }
            "key4":"value4",            
            "key1":"value1",
         }
```

and I want it sorted as

```
dict_1 = { 
        "key1":"value1",
        "key2":"value2",
        "key3":{
                "key3_1":"value3_1",
                "key3_3":"value3_3",                    
                }
        "key4":"value4",
        "key5":"value5",                        
        "key8":{
                "key8_1":"value8_1",
                "key8_2":"value8_2",
                "key8_5":[
                          "value8_5_1",                 
                          "value8_5_3",                 
                          ]                 
                }           
        "key9":"value9",
     }
```

Is there a method to do it?

**Please note:**

- potentially my `dict_1` could have several levels of subkeys (nested
  dictionaries) or subvalues (nested lists).
- I am using Python 2.7.17, and I cannot update it. But order is not
  preserved in dictionaries of Python versions previous to 3.7, so I bet
  the sorting has to be done by using the [OrderedDict](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict).

Comment: Is your python version 3.7 or above? Below 3.7 order of insertion is not preserved in dictionaries.

Comment: make a function that sorts a dict on the top level, then call it recursively on each node where the node is an instance of dict

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, it is important to know that dictionaries are not ordered. So, if you want to order a dict, you need to go with `collections.OrderedDict` (which exists since Python `2.7`).

And then, this is a use case for a recursive function:

```
from collections import OrderedDict


def order_dict(d):
    ordered_dict = OrderedDict()
    for key in sorted(d.keys()):
        val = d[key]
        if isinstance(val, dict):
            val = order_dict(val)
        ordered_dict[key] = val
    return ordered_dict
```