# How to sort all the nested dictionaries and lists inside a dictionary or list at once?

Tags: python, list, dictionary, nested, ordereddict

I am trying to develop the most efficient/comprehensive function with this aim:

> Sorting every nested dictionary or list inside a dictionary or list.

**Note:** I used the [`collections.OrderedDict`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict) because I wanted to make it useful also for python versions before the 3.7, the ones that does not preserve order in dictionaries.

Based on the recursive function from [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69028435/7658051), which sorts only nested dictionaries, I'm trying to build a correspondant recursive function that sorts only nested lists, and then to combine them by using if cycles that identify if the object to be sorted is a dictionary or a list.

This is what I have developed:

```
from collections import OrderedDict

def recursively_order_dict(d):
    ordered_dict = OrderedDict()
    for key in sorted(d.keys()):
        val = d[key]
        if isinstance(val, dict):
            val = recursively_order_dict(val)
        if isinstance(val, list):
            val = recursively_order_list(val)    
        ordered_dict[key] = val
    return ordered_dict

def recursively_order_list(l):
    ordered_list = []
    for element in sorted(l):
        if isinstance(element, list):
            element = recursively_order_list(element)
        if isinstance(element, dict):
            element = recursively_order_dict(element)
        ordered_list.append(element)
    return ordered_list 

def order_all_dicts_and_lists_in_iterable(iterable1):        
    if isinstance(iterable1, dict):
        ordered_iterable = recursively_order_dict(iterable1)            
    if isinstance(iterable1, list):
        ordered_iterable = recursively_order_list(iterable1)                   
    else:        
        print("%s\n is nor a list nor a dictionary.\nIts type is %s." % (iterable1, type(iterable1)) ) 
        return   
    return ordered_iterable
```

It works fine on many examples, but it does not by processing the dictionary `dict_2`

```
dict_2 = { 
        "key9":"value9",
        "key5":"value5",
        "key3":{
                "key3_1":"value3_1",
                "key3_5":"value3_5",
                "key3_2":[[],"value3_2_1",[] ],
                },
        "key2":"value2",
        "key8":{
                "key8_1":"value8_1",
                "key8_5":{
                            "key8_5_4":["value8_5_b", "value8_5_a", "value8_5_c"],
                            "key8_5_2":[{},{"key8_5_2_4_2":"value8_5_2_4_2", "key8_5_2_4_1":"value8_5_2_4_1", "key8_5_2_4_5":"value8_5_2_4_5"}, "value8_5_2_1",{}],
                            },
                "key8_2":"value8_2",
                },
        "key1":"value1",
     }

sorted_dict_2 = order_all_dicts_and_lists_in_iterable(dict_2)
```

and throws this error:

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------------- TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last) <ipython-input-12-9cbf4414127d> in <module>
----> 1 order_all_dicts_and_lists_in_iterable(dict_2)

<ipython-input-9-352b10801248> in order_all_dicts_and_lists_in_iterable(iterable1)
     26 
     27     if isinstance(iterable1, dict):
---> 28         ordered_iterable = recursively_order_dict(iterable1)
     29         if isinstance(iterable1, list):
     30             ordered_iterable = order_all_dicts_and_lists_in_iterable(ordered_iterable)

<ipython-input-9-352b10801248> in recursively_order_dict(d)
      6         val = d[key]
      7         if isinstance(val, dict):
----> 8             val = recursively_order_dict(val)
      9         if isinstance(val, list):
     10             val = recursively_order_list(val)

<ipython-input-9-352b10801248> in recursively_order_dict(d)
      8             val = recursively_order_dict(val)
      9         if isinstance(val, list):
---> 10             val = recursively_order_list(val)
     11         ordered_dict[key] = val
     12     return ordered_dict

<ipython-input-9-352b10801248> in recursively_order_list(l)
     14 def recursively_order_list(l):
     15     ordered_list = []
---> 16     for element in sorted(l):
     17         if isinstance(element, list):
     18             element = recursively_order_list(element)

TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'list'
```

So it looks like Python cannot sort iterable made of strings/numbers and lists/dictionaries, because it does not know what to take from lists/dictionaries as a term of comparison.

How could I change my function in order to get lists/dictionaries just being put at the end/start of the sorted iterable, when compared to strings/numbers ?

In few words, how should I change my function to have it turn the above `dict_2` into this (hand-edited) `sorted_dict_2`?

```
sorted_dict_2 = { 
            "key1":"value1",
            "key2":"value2",
            "key3":{
                    "key3_1":"value3_1",
                    "key3_2":[ [],[],"value3_2_1" ],
                    "key3_5":"value3_5",                    
                    },            
            "key5":"value5",           
            "key8":{
                    "key8_1":"value8_1",
                    "key8_2":"value8_2",
                    "key8_5":{                                
                                "key8_5_2":[
                                            {},
                                            {},
                                            "value8_5_2_1",
                                            {
                                            "key8_5_2_4_1":"value8_5_2_4_1",
                                            "key8_5_2_4_2":"value8_5_2_4_2",                                               
                                            "key8_5_2_4_5":"value8_5_2_4_5"
                                            },                                                                                        
                                            ],
                                "key8_5_4":["value8_5_a", "value8_5_b", "value8_5_c"],
                            },
                    
                    },
            "key9":"value9",
         }
```

Comment: I think this will be difficult if you can't put any constraint on the types you *expect*. For example, `[ [],[],"value3_2_1" ]` could  that also contains numbers? How should that case be handled?

Comment: Am I missing something? Inside `order_all_dicts_and_lists_in_iterable`, the first `if `is `if isinstance(iterable1, dict):`, but then nested inside, you check `if isinstance(iterable1, list):`, but that can never be true...

Comment: Thanks juanpa! I deleted the unreachable branches

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, basically, you need to make a key function that will make all containers compare less than anything else. A handy value is `float('inf')` for this. However, since we don't know if the thing we are sorting contains numbers or strings, we have to just transform everything into a tuple, and manually map the ordinal values for each string: `map(ord, x)`

The following is an example if you want containers to move to the front (so *negative* inf...:

```
from collections import OrderedDict

def recursively_order_dict(d):
    ordered_dict = OrderedDict()
    for key in sorted(d.keys()):
        val = d[key]
        if isinstance(val, dict):
            val = recursively_order_dict(val)
        if isinstance(val, list):
            val = recursively_order_list(val)
        ordered_dict[key] = val
    return ordered_dict

def _move_containers_to_end(x):
    if isinstance(x, (list, dict)):
        # to put at the end, use inf, at the start, -inf
        return (float('-inf'),)
    elif isinstance(x, str):
        return tuple(map(ord,  x))
    else: # assuming we only can get numbers at this point
        return (x,)

def recursively_order_list(l):
    ordered_list = []
    for element in sorted(l, key=_move_containers_to_end):
        if isinstance(element, list):
            element = recursively_order_list(element)
        if isinstance(element, dict):
            element = recursively_order_dict(element)
        ordered_list.append(element)
    return ordered_list

def order_all_dicts_and_lists_in_iterable(iterable1):
    if isinstance(iterable1, dict):
        ordered_iterable = recursively_order_dict(iterable1)
    elif isinstance(iterable1, list):
        ordered_iterable = recursively_orded_list(iterable1)
    else:
        print("%s\n is nor a list nor a dictionary.\nIts type is %s." % (iterable1, type(iterable1)) )
    return ordered_iterable
```

The result of the above is:

```
OrderedDict([('key1', 'value1'),
             ('key2', 'value2'),
             ('key3',
              OrderedDict([('key3_1', 'value3_1'),
                           ('key3_2', [[], [], 'value3_2_1']),
                           ('key3_5', 'value3_5')])),
             ('key5', 'value5'),
             ('key8',
              OrderedDict([('key8_1', 'value8_1'),
                           ('key8_2', 'value8_2'),
                           ('key8_5',
                            OrderedDict([('key8_5_2',
                                          [OrderedDict(),
                                           OrderedDict([('key8_5_2_4_1',
                                                         'value8_5_2_4_1'),
                                                        ('key8_5_2_4_2',
                                                         'value8_5_2_4_2'),
                                                        ('key8_5_2_4_5',
                                                         'value8_5_2_4_5')]),
                                           OrderedDict(),
                                           'value8_5_2_1']),
                                         ('key8_5_4',
                                          ['value8_5_a',
                                           'value8_5_b',
                                           'value8_5_c'])]))])),
             ('key9', 'value9')])
```

Note, you may want to do something like:

```
import sys:
if sys.version_info.minor < 7:
    OrderedMapping = dict
else:
    from collections import OrderedDict as OrderedMapping
```

Then use:

```
ordered_dict = OrderedMapping()
```

in `recursively_order_dict`